# Radix sort using a CSV file

Tags: sorting, data-structures

I've got an assignment today and I have no idea how can I sort a csv file using radix sort. 
The Question is:

**Performance of Radix Sort**

1. Memory Space Requirements
2. Time in Seconds
3. Time Complexity O(??)
4. How many data movements/swapping was there?
5. How many comparisons were performed?

Comment: nice . what else you want?

Comment: I bet there exists a wikipedia page giving full and explained answers to all these questions.

Comment: You don't have a question, you want people to do your homework for you. That's very unrespectful

Comment: If only there were some way to search SO for "radix sort".